# Search for JSON data in node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to find a specific value under a condition in my json file. At the moment I use filter but whenever I use filter it gives me an error `jsonData.filter is not a function`

How would you be able to find a specific value in the `servers.json` file?

**node.js**

```
//check if data exists 
 var jsonData = fs.readFileSync('servers.json','utf8');
  
 console.log(text);

 var result =  jsonData.filter(v => v.id === message.guild.id);
```

**json data**

```
[
  {
  "id": "725475771321155605",
  "name": "test server"
  },
  {
    "id": "732421155602342345",
    "name": "test server1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter is a method to be used in array, but when you use `fs.readFileSync('servers.json','utf8');`, you get pure json data. Hence why you get that error.

You first need to parse that json by using JSON.parse(). Then use your filter.

```
 const jsonData = fs.readFileSync('servers.json','utf8');
 const parsedData= JSON.parse(jsonData);

 const result = object.filter(v => v.id === message.guild.id);
```

It might be tricky but there is a slight difference between the json and the parsed object.

If you conle.log the data, this is the output without JSON.parse

```
[{
  "id": "725475771321155605",
  "name": "test server"
},
{
  "id": "725475771321155605",
  "name": "test server"
}
]
```

and this is what you get when pasing.

```
[
  { id: '725475771321155605', name: 'test server' },
  { id: '725475771321155605', name: 'test server' }
]
```

Can you see the difference here?